# How to transform xml to xml with multiple values and multi tags separated by space

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to transform the below "input.xml" to "output.xml"

**input.xml**

```
<tags><tag1>1 2 3</tag1><tag2>A B C</tag2></tags>
```

**output.xml**

```
<tags>
 <tag1>1</tag1>
 <tag2>A</tag2>
</tags>

<tags>
 <tag1>2</tag1>
 <tag2>B</tag2>
</tags>

<tags>
 <tag1>3</tag1>
 <tag2>c</tag2>
</tags>
```

Assumption that number of values of `<tag1>`, `<tag2>` will be same.

Comment: Which version of xslt are you using ?

Comment: XSLT version="2.0"

Comment: can you share what you have attempted and what is the exact problem you are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="tokenizedTag1" select="tokenize(/tags/tag1,' ')" />
    <xsl:variable name="tokenizedTag2" select="tokenize(/tags/tag2,' ')" />

    <xsl:for-each select="$tokenizedTag1">
        <xsl:variable name="positionTag1" select="position()"></xsl:variable>
        <tags>
            <tag1><xsl:value-of select="." /></tag1>
            <xsl:for-each select="$tokenizedTag2">
                <xsl:if test="$positionTag1 = position()">
                    <tag2><xsl:value-of select="." /></tag2>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tags>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQfo